# From 1 to 100 select 26 distinct numbers: pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

From 1 to 100 select 26 distinct numbers, there must exist one number which divides the product of the other 25 numbers.

This seems to be an easy application of the pigeonhole principle, but I could not figure out the exact argument. Can someone help?

Comment: Perhaps working modulo 4 is the way.

Answer (score 0):

Hint to get you started:

- How many primes numbers are there less than $100$?

Comment: I went to that step (which shows 25 is not enough), and I thought of constructing 25 pigeonholes based on the 25 primes, but then I am stuck.

Comment: I suspect the next step is to say that clearly you cannot have $1$, so you must have a composite number.  But $25$ primes and a composite will not do either, as you cannot have a prime which divides the composite, so you must have two composites and that just makes things worse as they cannot divide each other, so you are now blocking at least two primes, so you must have three composites. At least one of them must block a third prime (try to find an example involving just two primes where none of the three composites divides the product of the other two composites) and so on.

Comment: Thanks. But the proof is still unclear for me. Could you please write a bit more formal argument?